# Django Using Multiple Models with Same Table & Field Names?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django project where I need to use **old** database and **new** database source between pages. They both have same table names and fields names but are loaded with different data.

Now, these are actual models that are already in place loaded with data so it is not like I can start from scratch and design two models with unique names.

The question is. Can I have multiple models with the same table names? How do I distinguish them in my `models.py`?

Then, how do I tell Django in my `view.py` which model to use if they have a same table name and same field names? BTW each view will be using one or the other models, so it is not like I need to use both at the same time.

Old DB:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', ...
    state = models.CharField( ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(...
```

New DB:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', ...
    state = models.CharField( ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(...
```

Comment: Are they *exactly* the same? Check the sites framework

Comment: Another way is to define different DBs in the settings.py file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @Alvaro The are exactly the same, I do have the the sites framework implemented but is is running on the same domain so I'm not sure what the sites framework would do with this. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Also if I use the `using` option in my view `Author.objects.using('default').all()` how do I distinguish those two in my `models.py`?

Comment: Can you separate these models to different files (models_old.py / models_new.py) and then import them as needed?

Comment: @koressak that may be doable. How would I go about that? Do I need anything in the `__init__.py` or do I just use `class Business(models_old.Model) in the actual model file?

Comment: @WayBehind why should yo distinguish them? use the same models.py for both...

Comment: @Alvaro are you saying I can add two models with the same class name? `class Business(models.Model):` How will Django knows which one is which?

Comment: @WayBehind What actually is the thing you are trying to accomplish? You have part of the database still in the old "system" and not migrated to the new one? If so, would'n it be better to just migrate the dataset and not worry about the models?

I just want to say, that if there are different data sources you want to merge, there will be a different database settings to Model meta class and I would put them to different py file altogether.

Comment: @koressak I wish I could just migrate the DB. Unfortunately, we are dealing with multiple websites that are sharing some new data and the migration process is pretty much based on slowly switching pages to source from the new DB. As per using two different files, how do I import the "new" model and how do I name the class so Django knows this model source is the "new" DB?

Comment: @WayBehind The models.py file defines the structure of the database. If your databases share the same structure, you must use the same file. Django will know which DB to query based on your .using()

Comment: @Alvaro I have tried that but unfortunately it doesnt work as the database structure is not 100% identical and the new DB has some new fields and some fields from the old DB are no longer in place. I tried to create new file `models_new.py` and even imported the model in my `view.py` as `business_new` however Django is still trying to use the old DB structure even with the `.using('new_db')` and is throwing `missing field` errors.

Comment: I see... this is a quite complex case. You'll have to either rename your new model entirely or use the old database with SQL and build custom objects to represent them or, alternatively, create a custom manager, 'old_objects' maybe, that executes the query against the old database and creates the 'new' Business instances by hand

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you again for your help! I appreciate the effort! I'm quite disappointed that Django is incapable of handling such a basic issue as easily using 2 database sources. All I'm trying to do, is to tell Django "here is my second DB, this is the DB structure ... show me the data".

Comment: I  think the problem is more conceptual here.. django doesn't work that way (I think RoR would be better as it instrospects the database). In django, your model must be consistent with the database and it's name must be unique. If you have an outdated DB, then you should use a different model name, since django doesn't *know* in which state your db is... it'll just use the queries that make sense with your current models.py

Comment: How about defining an OldBusiness model, and specify the table name to be business? You could override the manager to ONLY use the old DB

Answer (score 3):

Following the discussion, I've come up with this idea:

1) Change your DATABASES setting to point to two different DBs. You can check it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/)

2) Change your model definition to include both versions and point to the same table. Testing with version 1.7, django will overlook this in model validation, but be **very** careful with migrations:

```
class OldBusiness(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_business'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', ...
    state = models.CharField( ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(...


class Business(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_business'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', ...
    state = models.CharField( ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(...
```

3) Override the object manager to make sure you are using the right db for any query:

```
class OldManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OldManager, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).using('old')


class OldBusiness(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_business'

    objects = OldManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', ...
    state = models.CharField( ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(...
```

That *should* do it for most practical cases, but if you are updating, you'll have to take other things into account.

As a note: this assumes you left the new database in the "default" key in the DATABASES dict

*A very good improvement would be to implement a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) for the OldBusiness model*

You could even check for model name and return the old db in that case. Very clean and would work with migrations

Comment: thank you again for your help. I will definitely try this approach. BTW the old DB is the default DB and the app is running on Django 1.6 if that makes any difference. Thanks again!